# Passing in a key results in extra characters in my firebase URL, how do I remove them?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

When placing the "key" variable inside of this string, it displays 'simplelogin%3A5' instead of 'simplelogin:5'. Is there a way to just pass in the latter?

```
  var populateTasks = function(date, key){
    $scope.ref = new Firebase("https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/users/"+key+"/tasks");   
  };
```

results in: https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/users/simplelogin%3A5/tasks
I need: https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com/users/simplelogin:5/tasks

Comment: I just tried this myself with a demo url and was unable to reproduce this using `simplelogin:5`. This suggests that your key is already encoded when you concatenate it. You should proved more data on where this key came from (a URI presumably), which would be critical to an accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var uri = "//what you need to convert";
var uri_dec = decodeURIComponent(uri);
var res = uri_dec;
```

Answer (score 1):

Where does the value of `key` come from? If you get it from a URL, it makes sense that you see `%3A`.

A `:` has a special meaning in a URL, so it is escaped. And the URL escape sequence for a `:` is `%3A`.

To convert the `%3A` back to `:` you simply unescape it like this:

```
unescape(key)
```

Or use `decodeURIComponent`, which in this case accomplishes the same. The best way to decode the value depends on why it was encoded in the first place, hence my initial question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried trimming key before concatenating it to the URL?

```
key = key.trim();
```

Comment: It's not a problem of spaces, but the : in the center of the id, which is escaped by the web browser.